# how can i use index.php instead of index.html in cordova?

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a developed index.php file which is working perfectly fine in a web server and connecting with MySQL database.But now i need to use the same index.php to convert to an application and package it to device file formats(.apk, .ipx).
I have read it [here](HTTP://phonegap.com/about/FAQ/) that the network requests are to be made in xmlhttprequest , but i need to launch an index.php instead of index,html file. 
How should i proceed?
Reference : http://phonegap.com/about/faq/

EDIT:
I am aware that the native framework looks for index,html as it is a webview, but need a workaround for this

EDIT: i have a webserver with phpmysql installed to communicate with the app.
All i am looking is to load index,php file instead if index.html (because cordova looks only fot index,html file).

Comment: The index.php file needs to be running on an external server and your javascript should use XMLHTTPRequest to get/post data to the server. If you want the app to do everything instead, you'll need to use javascript for the logic.

Comment: Basically you can't execute php code in cordova. You'll need a webserver that supports php and try communicate between the webserver and your app

Answer (score 0):

you can change the content of config.xml file in the root directory of your cordova project to load index.php instead of index.html

Comment: As for newbies in configuring config.xml, how do you achieve this one? Could you provide a snippet to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an index.html file that says:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url="index.php">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cordova supports only html files as the app's starting page in the content of the config.xml.

PHP being server side script needs to be hosted on a web server.

To open a .php page on default in a cordova app the html file should redirect to the php resource.

Add the following  in the index.html code:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(true);
        window.location.href = "url containing the index.php resource file.";
    };
</script>
```